# Replace instant purchase message with popup (2.2)

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, modal-popup, instant-purchase

I'm using a custom theme I wrote that derives from magento-blank and was wondering how I might go about replacing the instant purchase message at the top with a popup. Currently, on a mobile device, that message is hard to see, and I'm worried people are going to think it didn't work and click the button a bunch of times.

I can code if need be. I just need a push in the right direction, as I'm still pretty new to Magento. I'm on 2.2.6.

Thanks!